# emacs: close buffers list on selection

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a configuration hook to make the "*Buffers List*" buffer automatically closing when a buffer is selected in such window?
Each time the buffer list opens and I select a buffer I have to manually close it using
`C-x C-k`
and this is annoying, also because it leaves the frame split in at least two windows.

Comment: Try [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki). It will change your Emacs experience forever. You will be able close, preview and search within buffers directly from the buffers list. If you use `(helm-mode 1)`, helm will replace most Emacs menus with the corresponding helm equivalent.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure about a config option, but you can always use <kbd>q</kbd> (or a <kbd>C-x 1</kbd> in your current buffer) instead of <kbd>C-x C-k</kbd> to close the temp buffer.

P.S. Almost nobody uses `buffer-list` these days. Most Emacs users simply remap it to **ibuffer** (its much smarter and you might like the fact that its temp buffer disappears by default):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
```

Comment: Help about ibuffer at: [emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode). You might not need to "install", it may already be part of your standard emacs installation, just try `M-x ibuffer <RET>` and see.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak this function for your requirement:

```
(defun kill-other-buffers ()
  "Kill all other buffers."
  (interactive)
  (mapc 'kill-buffer (delq (current-buffer) (buffer-list))))
```

This code kills all the buffers except the current one. Source: [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KillingBuffers#toc2)